# actualización de ecplise a la versión 2024-03

Tags: eclipse

Después de actualizar a la ultima versión de eclipse no puedo utilizar mi espacio de trabajo.
También me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.